# Look up / join data with AngularFire

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I've got a question on how to combine data from different Firebase database nodes before displaying it on the frontend. I've got a Firebase database with the following structure. (I'm new to a nosql setup, so this looks more relational):

```
{
  "agents" : {
    "-KPCmnwzjd8CeSdrU3As" : {
    "contactNumber" : "12345",
    "name" : "aaa"
    },
    "-KPCmw6dKuopDlsMVOlU" : {
     "contactNumber" : "123",
     "name" : "bbb"
    },
    "-KPCoWcLecpchcFV-vh_" : {
     "contactNumber" : "123",
     "name" : "ccc"
    },
    "-KPROMhPatLjVxMdvfLf" : {
     "contactNumber" : "256342",
     "name" : "blah"
    },
    "-KPWIFl5qp5FvAeC3YhG" : {
     "contactNumber" : "123",
     "name" : "eee"
    }
  },
  "listings" : {
    "-KPWKTvW3GzFEIT2hUNU" : {
      "agent" : "-KPCoWcLecpchcFV-vh_",
      "description" : "third",
      "reference" : "REF1"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Firebase SDK 3.2.0 and AngularFire 2.0.1. In my Angular app I am able to get the list of listings, and for each one look up the agent information. The reason I'm not storing the agent info with the listing is I want the ability to update the agent and the change should reflect on all listings. I don't want to have to go and update all listings if the agent telephone number changes (as an example).

In my controller I have the following:

```
// get the listings
var listingsRef = firebase.database().ref().child('listings');
vm.listings = $firebaseArray(listingsRef);

// this will move to my ui-router as a resolve but for simplicity's sake
// I added it here...
vm.listings.$loaded().then(function(data){
  // loop through the listings...
  data.forEach(function(listing) {
    if (listing.agent) {
      // get the agent for the listing 
      listing.agent = AgentFactory.getAgent(listing.agent);
    }
  });
});
```

Right now the data is displaying correctly on the frontend. There is a slight delay with the agent data showing because of the need of the getAgent promise to resolve.

My questions are:
Is this the correct way of getting the agent data? Should I be looping through the listings and for each query the agent data? How do I wait / keep track of all of the getAgents to resolve?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've structured my data similarly. If you want to wait for all the `getAgents` to resolve you can use `$q.all`. I'm not entirely sure what your `AgentFactory.getAgent` is returning, but let's assume it's a `$firebaseObject`. If that's the case inject `$q` and then do the following:

```
vm.listings.$loaded().then(function (data) {
    // loop through the listings...
    var promises = [];
    data.forEach(function (listing) {
        if (listing.agent) {
            // get the agent for the listing
            listing.agent = AgentFactory.getAgent(listing.agent);
            promises.push(listing.agent.$loaded());
        }
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
}).then(function (agents) {
    //all agents are loaded
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help. That worked great. Yes, the getAgent call returns a firebaseObject. Just out of interest, do you think there is any performance issues with querying it like this? From what I've read Firebase does a lot of optimising and caching internally.

Comment: Nope, from my understanding it should be just fine.